# Launch silverlight application out of browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm using **sllauncher.exe** to execute a local silverlight 4 application, but the launcher show the next error: Invalid parameters.

How can I execute a silverlight application out of browser?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post how you are trying to launch it, i.e. params etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Heuer has some good info on the subject:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx